# Get Facebook Auth token from Azure Easy API

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, facebook-access-token

Easy API are very poorly documented, I'm trying to get the Facebook Auth token from a user authenticated against it through Azure, I've created an API with the following GET:

```
module.exports = {
    "get": function (req, res, next) {
        res.json(req.user.getIdentity("facebook"));
    }
};
```

However azure responds with "cannot read property 'getIdentity' from undefined". If user is undefined in res, where can I get it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy APIs is documented in the Azure Mobile Apps Node.js SDK HOWTO and within the API docs.  You can find the HOWTO here:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/

As to the specific question, getIdentity() is a Promise-based mechanism. In addition, you need to access the user object through the azureMobile property.  Something like:

```
module.exports = {
    "get": function (req, res, next) {
        req.azureMobile.user.getIdentity("facebook").then((data) => {
            res.status(200).type('application/json').json(data);
        }).catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian.  I have spent hours trying to find the code to accomplish this.  This should be added (and highlighted) into the Mobile Apps Authentication documentation (along with the code required to get details from the other 3 main services).  This functionality is fundamental to a lot of apps, but the information was really hard to find.  Most of the would be solutions don't work because they were created for Az Mobile Services not Az Mobile Apps.

Comment: Not disagreeing - I do not work for Microsoft, so can't do anything about their documentation.