# Getting User information from identity provider and Azure EasyAPI

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to create an Azure EasyAPI to get some user information from the identity provider (microsoft) in my app. However, I'm getting an error from all of the examples I've found online and none of the answers I've found on stackoverflow have helped.

Error:

```
Azure Log:    
    : Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure-mobile-apps\src\auth\getIdentity.js:35:55)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:903:12)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:439:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
```

Code:

```
    module.exports = {
"get": function (request, response, next) {
    request.azureMobile.user.getIdentity('microsoftaccount').then(function (data) {
        var accessToken = data.microsoftaccount.access_token;
        var url = 'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/?method=GET&access_token=' + accessToken;
        var requestCallback = function (err, resp, body) {
            if (err || resp.statusCode !== 200) {
                console.error('Error sending data to the provider: ', err);
                response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, body);
            } else {
                try {
                    var userData = JSON.parse(body);
                    response.send(200, userData);
                } catch (ex) {
                    console.error('Error parsing response from the provider API: ', ex);
                    response.send(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex);
                }
            }
            var req = require('request');
        var reqOptions = {
            uri: url,
            headers: { Accept: "application/json" }
        };
        req(reqOptions, requestCallback);
        };  
        }).catch(function (error) {
        response.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(error));
    });

        //...

}};
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878102/get-facebook-auth-token-from-azure-easy-api

Comment: This changed the error -- now, in my c# code, when I await the API invocation, it takes a really long time and eventually times out. In my Azure output, I get "silly: GetIdentity Request:  hostname=vflash.azurewebsites.net, port=443, path=/.auth/me?provider=[object Object], method=GET, + a really long string

Answer (score 1):

In [API Documentation](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_auth_user.html#~getIdentity) of Azure Mobile Apps for Node.js, it indicates that the `getIdentity` method accepts the name of the authentication provider as a parameter and returns a promise that yields the identity information on success.

So your code should look like:

```
module.exports = {
    "get": function (req, res, next) {
        req.azureMobile.user.getIdentity('microsoftaccount').then(function (data) {
            var accessToken = data.microsoftaccount.access_token;
            //...
        }).catch(function (error) {
            res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
}
```

Another option to get the user info is to call `/.auth/me` endpoint.

```
var https = require('https');

module.exports = {
    "get": function (request, response, next) {

        var token = request.azureMobile.user.token;

        var options = {
            hostname: '<yourappname>.azurewebsites.net',
            port: 443,
            path: '/.auth/me',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'x-zumo-auth': token
            }
        };

        var req = https.request(options, (res) => {

            var str = '';
            res.on('data', (d) => {
                str += d;
            });

            res.on('end', function () {
                console.log(str);
                response.status(200).type('application/json').json(str);
            });
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
            console.error(e);
        });
        req.end();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, I'm still having issues. Please, if you can, take a look at my update to the original question. Sorry, I don't really know node.js. Thanks!

Comment: Can you get the `authenticationToken` which is stored in `request.azureMobile.user.token`?

Comment: Well, no matter what I change the code to, I keep getting the same error. I took out everything except the getIdentity function and console.log and am still getting the unexpected end of input error. And my brackets and parentheses are all matched correctly.

Comment: Hi @user3007447, I updated my reply. Could you have a try to call `/.auth/me` to get the user info?

Comment: Unfortunately, the new code is giving no output in the Azure log and is giving no data inside of my client app.